# How to build libsmbclient.a

Tags: static-libraries, samba, libsmbclient

I want to build **libsmbclient.a**. This library must then be statically included in the C++ project. I see there is **wscript_build** in **samba/source4/torture/libsmbclient**. But this script build module, not library.

If I build with
`>>./configure --prefix=/home/user/samba-static --bundled-libraries=ALL --with-static-modules=ALL --nonshared-binary=client/smbclient`
I get вinary executable file **smbclient** and shared library file **libsmbclient.so**. But I need static library.